# Quorum - oversized data during contract creation - contract code size limit

Tags: contract-deployment, quorum

While creating contract, I am getting the error "oversized data" during contract creation.

Other than modifying the go-ethereum code file to increase the maxCodeSize, or splitting the contracts up, are there any other workarounds?

Why should there be a contract code size limit in a private blockchain in the first place?

Comment: You can try enabling optimization in the solidity compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by increasing the transaction size to 64KB in tx_pool.go

DOS is less applicable for private Ethereum networks such as Quorum.

// Heuristic limit, reject transactions over 32KB to prevent DOS attacks

// UPDATED to 64KB to support the deployment of bigger contract due to the pressing need for sophisticated/complex contract in financial/capital markets - Nathan Aw

```
if tx.Size() > 64*1024 {
    return ErrOversizedData
}
```

References:

https://github.com/nathanawmk/quorum/blob/master/core/tx_pool.go

Comment: Adding to the (correct) Nathan Aw answer. There is an open issue in Ethereum EIP regarding this subject:
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/659

Answer (score 2):

GoQuorum allows to configure the contract dize limit by using `maxCodeSize` and `maxCodeSizeConfig` arguments in the genesis file (the latter allows to configure by block). More information on https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/en/stable/HowTo/Configure/GenesisOptions/#contract-code-size.

Those values can be configured between 24kb and 128kb.

Comment: I asked this 2 years back. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing this limit to check tx.Size does help, but it won't get you far as there are two more limits for large transactions:

- There is a limit for RPC calls, it's in rpc/http.go:

```
maxRequestContentLength = 1024 * 128
```

- There is a maximum size for contract code, which is particularly relevant when you are deploying contracts. It is called `MaxCodeSize` and it is configured in params/protocol_params.go:

```
MaxCodeSize = 24576
```

Altogether, the whole thing is calibrated to set the limit around 8 mill units of gas. To go well over that limit you can fork quorum and change all four things: max block gas, value in tx.Size check, maxRequestContentLength for RPC calls, and MaxCodeSize

I forked and patched a quorum version at https://github.com/juliofaura/quorum/tree/largertxs that should do the trick. I deployed a large contract that took a good 35 mill units of gas, and all good ;-)

Also - pantheon is built with a 16 Mb transaction size limit, which essentially fixes all this